# Fetch the latest tweet from Twitter with Tweepy

Tags: python, web-scraping, tweepy

I want to fetch the latest tweet if the keyword is met from a bounch of users at Twitter in real time.

This code fetchs the latest tweet if 'Twitter' keyword is met, and stores it in the "store" variable every 5 seconds and goes on forever.

Is there a way to make it to only fetch the tweet if it isent already present in the store variable. And if its already there it should stay on and search for the next tweet but not fetch it?

```
import tweepy
import time

api = 'APIKEY'
apisq = 'APISQ'
acc_tok = 'TOK'
acc_sq = 'TOkSQ'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api, apisq)
auth.set_access_token(acc_tok, acc_sq)
api = tweepy.API(auth)


store = []

username = 'somename'

while True:
    first = []
    get_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=username, count=1)
    test = get_tweets[0]
    first.append(test.text)
    time.sleep(5)
    if any('Twitter' in word for word in first):
        store.append(first)
        print(store)
    else:
        continue
```

Ive tried with some Conditional Statements but has not been very succesful yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think the important piece of data would be the 'id' field returned in the list. You could either add the tweets to a dictionary where the key would be the 'id' and the value the text of the tweet, or create a second list that contains the 'id' and then create a filter condition to validate that the 'id' isn't present in the other list before adding the new tweet.
The dictionary method is likely the quickest computationally, but the second list method is likely the easiest conceptually.